# Where are the instructions for installing the 2.71 Release Candidate?

Tags: windows, installation

I've downloaded the Zip file for Windows 64Bit and unpacked it and now have a folder with 226Mb of files that includes a Blender.exe.
I however, couldn't find any installation instructions either in the readme or the created folder structure.
I'm trying to set up 2.71 for production testing.  How do I do that or where do I find instructions on how to do that?
Thanks
John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that folder you unzipped, just double click on the blender.exe file.  There is no need to "install" blender like you are thinking. Blender runs straight from the unzipped folder.

Comment: It appears to work as you described

Answer (score 5):

The Release Candidate seems to be only released as a zip file. This can be unzipped wherever you want and run from the folder, it doesn't need to install.

If you download the latest *official* release of Blender, currently 2.70, then you have the option of either downloading a regular installer or a zip again.